# <sjg:grid> edit inline control navigator buttons to display

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin, struts2-jquery-grid

Using the below sjg:grid with edit inline. This displays the edit navigator buttons Add New Row, Edit selected row, Save, Cancel row editing.

I don't want to show the Add new row button in the navigator. How to do this?

```
<s:url var="searchUrl" action="SearchAction"/>
<s:url var="editSearchUrl" action="editSearchAction"/>
<sjg:grid
    id="searchGridId"
    formIds="searchFormId"
    href="%{searchUrl}"
    reloadTopics="reloadSearchGrid"
    dataType="json" 
    pager="true"
    gridModel="searchResults"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    rownumbers="true"
    viewrecords="true"
    autowidth="true"
    editurl="%{editSearchUrl}"
    editinline="true"
    navigator="true"
    navigatorAdd="false"
    navigatorViewOptions="{height:280, width:500}"
    navigatorDelete="false"
    navigatorEdit="false"
    navigatorRefresh="true"
    navigatorSearch="false"
    multiselect="false"
    onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
>       
<sjg:gridColumn name="orderNumber" index="orderNumber" title="%  {getText   ('label.orderNumber')}" key="true" sortable="true"/>

<sjg:gridColumn name="orderRange" index="orderRange" title="%{getText('label.orderRange)}" sortable="false" editable="true" edittype="select" editoptions="{value:'=:=;&lt;:&lt;;&gt;:&gt;'}"/>  
</sjg:grid>
```

Comment: Read the docs on the site.